# UPDATE SQLite, how to get numbers of affected changed rows (not the found matched rows)

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

Nowhere I found the solution to retrieve the numbers of affected changed rows (not the found matched rows).
Each solution are "found/matched rows" only :

- [SELECT CHANGES()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes)
- PHP PDO : $stmt->[rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

But i want know the real number of rows updated (whith differents values only before the update statement).

Looking on [SQL "matching found rows" vs "affected rows"](http://dotclear.placeoweb.com/post/SQL-matching-found-rows-vs-affected-rows), neither command line, neither connector PHP PDO was able to return the number of real changed rows.

To resume, with :

```
CREATE TABLE table_update_count ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 'val' VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO table_update_count (val) VALUES ('AA');
INSERT INTO table_update_count (val) VALUES ('AB');
UPDATE table_update_count SET val = 'AB';
```

Result obtained : 2

Expected result : 1

I there a way to do that ?

I don't seem to be alone wishing this improvement...

Comment: Your problem is the SQLite, it isn't support what you want because it didn't compare if the row had a real change, just if it matches to update.

Answer (score 3):

The UPDATE statement updates *two* rows. That the new value happens to be identical with the old value does not matter, as far as this count is concerned.

If you do not want to count rows with the same values, you have to manually filter them out:

```sql
UPDATE table_update_count
SET val = 'AB'
WHERE val IS NOT 'AB';
```

Comment: Yes but with dynamically query it's impossible to know if there was a change.
For exemple, under Android, without declare each "NOT NEW value" column in WHERE clause :
`public int updateContact(int id, Contact contact) {`
`ContentValues values = new ContentValues();`
`values.put(COL_NAME, contact.getName());`
`values.put(COL_PHONE, contact.getPhone());`
`return bdd.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, COL_ID + " = " + id, null);`
`}`
Visibly the database don't do that natively... and there is no way without change the where clause.